# Swagger - Invalid JSON errors

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm just starting with Swagger UI and I'm trying to understand how it works.
So far I've entered some JSON (manually) and this is the result:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "PhakeApps API",
        "contact": {
            "name": "PhakeApps API team",
            "url": "http://phakeapps.com/"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Creative Commons 4.0 International",
            "url": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/"
        }
    },
    "host": "api.phakeapps.com",
    "basePath": "/v1",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/places/search": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Places"
                ],
                "description": "Search for (a) place(s) <br /><br /> <b>id</b> - The ID of the request. <br /> <b>api_key</b> - API Key for the platform the request is sent. <i>Currently, not required.</i> <br /> <b>Params</b> - Required. <i>See model & model schema.</i>",
                "operationId": "PlacesSearch",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "request",
                        "in": "body",
                        "paramType": "body",
                        "description": "Object containing the <u>id</u>, <u>api_key</u> and certain <u>params</u>.",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Search"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/PlacesResult"
                        }
                    },
                    "403": {
                        "description": "Validation error or Server Failure",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "PlacesResult": {
            "required": [
                "data",
                "id",
                "code"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Places"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "code": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                }
            }
        },
        "Places": {
            "required": [
                "places"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "places": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Place"
                }
            }
        },
        "City": {
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "Neighbourhood": {
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "Cuisine": {
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "Place": {
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name",
                "city",
                "neighbourhood",
                "address",
                "cuisine",
                "price",
                "photos_cnt",
                "lat",
                "lng",
                "is_fav"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "city": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/City"
                    }
                },
                "neighbourhood": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Neighbourhood"
                    }
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "cuisine": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Cuisine"
                    }
                },
                "price": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "photos_cnt": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "lat": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "lng": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "is_fav": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                }
            }
        },
        "Search": {
            "required": [
                "id",
                "api_key",
                "params"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "api_key": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "params": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/SearchParams"
                }
            }
        },
        "SearchParams": {
            "required": [
                "user_id",
                "city_id",
                "people",
                "dt",
                "locale"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "user_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "956dda4c21c72e48f5f17a7cd783a0f7"
                },
                "city_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "4ec4b3e6098c9d23c925b0c2451eb06a"
                },
                "people": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32",
                    "minimum": 1,
                    "default": 2
                },
                "dt": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32",
                    "default": "1427742000"
                },
                "locale": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "bg"
                },
                "place_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "0"
                },
                "neighborhood_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "0"
                },
                "cuisine_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "0"
                },
                "kids_place": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                },
                "price": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64",
                    "default": 1
                },
                "outdoors": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "default": false
                }
            }
        },
        "Error": {
            "required": [
                "code",
                "data"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "data": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, swagger's validator says it's not valid. The error I get is this

```
[
    {
        "level": "error",
        "domain": "validation",
        "keyword": "anyOf",
        "message": "instance failed to match at least one required schema among 2",
        "schema": {
            "loadingURI": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "pointer": "/properties/type"
        },
        "instance": {
            "pointer": "/definitions/Place/properties/lat/type"
        }
    }
]
```

Note that it works as expected (so far). It displays the data (models and models' structure) properly. Make requests and retrieves responses. Yet the validator says it's not valid. (The yellow badge saying 'Invalid', not the red one that says 'Error').

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your spec is indeed not valid. In your `Place` definition, you use `"type": "double"` to describe the type of the `lat` (and also `lng`) property, but such a type does not exist.

If you want to describe a numeric value of 'double' size, you should change the definition as follows:

```
            "lng": {
                "type": "number",
                "format": "double"
            }
```

Do that everywhere you use the `double` type, and it should resolve that issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yet the error still remains the same.

Comment: I just tested it, and the error has changed. There are additional problems with the spec, but *that* error is fixed with this solution.

Comment: As an added bonus, the other error is that you're using `paramType` to in the parameter of the operation, which is not a valid property. Remove that, and your spec should validate.

Comment: Amazing how I made the exact same mistake. Thanks